# Brezis' exercise 5.22.1: non-linear contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, lipschitz-functions, weak-topology

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $C$ be a non-empty closed convex subset of $H$. Let $T:C \to C$ be $1$-Lipschitz, i.e.,
> $$
> |Tu-T v| \le |u-v|
> \quad \forall u,v \in C.
> $$
>
> 1. Let $(u_n) \subset C$ and $u,f \in H$ such that $u_n \to u$ in the weak topology $\sigma(H, H^*)$ and $(u_n-Tu_n) \to f$ in norm topology. Then $u-Tu = f$. [**Hint:** Start with the case $C=H$ and use the inequality $\langle (u-Tu) - (v-Tv), u-v \ge 0$ for all $u,v \in H$]

My below proof does not follow the hint by the author. It seems more direct and simpler than the [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/312120/368425) following the hint.

> Could you confirm if my attempt contains some logical mistakes?

---

We define $F:C \to H$ by $Fv:= v-Tv$. We have $C$ is closed in $\sigma(H, H^*)$, so $u \in C$. We need to prove that $Fu=f$. Because $T$ is $1$-Lipschitz, we get
$$
\begin{align}
|u-u_n|^2 &\ge|Tu-Tu_n|^2 \\
&= |(Fu-Fu_n)-(u-u_n)|^2 \\
&= |Fu-Fu_n|^2 - 2 \langle Fu-Fu_n, u-u_n \rangle + |u-u_n|^2.
\end{align}
$$

Then $2 \langle Fu-Fu_n, u-u_n \rangle \ge |Fu-Fu_n|^2$. We have $(Fu-Fu_n)_n$ converges in norm, while $(u-u_n)_n$ converges to $0$ in $\sigma(H, H^*)$. This implies $\lim_n \langle Fu-Fu_n, u-u_n \rangle=0$. The claim then follows from $0 \ge  \lim_n |Fu-Fu_n|^2 = |Fu-f|^2$.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much for your verification!